# chemmacros \iupac command breaks in achemso's \title

Tags: errors, chemmacros, achemso

I'm getting an error when using `\iupac` inside `\title` with the `achemso` class:

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\title{Study of \iupac{1,2-di|methyl|benzene}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This is the error:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Undefined control sequence.
\l__chemmacros_tmpa_tl ->1,2-
                             di|methyl|benzene
l.7 \begin{document}
```

Everything looks good with `article`, or with the same `\iupac` command in the body and not in the title.

Comment: It should be fixed in the next release of `chemmacros`: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in `chemmacros` v5.11 (2020/03/07).

---

There is a slight timing issue with `achemso`/`chemmacros`. First `achemso` redefines `\begin{document}` to add `\maketitle` at the end. Then `chemmacros` loads `etoolbox`, which then appends `\@afterendpreamblehook` to `\document` (so now `\begin{document}` is equivalent to `\begin{document}\maketitle\@afterendpreamblehook`).

The problem is that `\iupac` makes several characters active, and this is best not done in the preamble, so `chemmacros` delays this making-active with `\AfterEndPreamble`, so things only get their definition in `\@afterendpreamblehook`, so you can see where this is going. At the time the title is used, in `\maketitle`, it is a bit too early to use `\iupac`, though it probably shouldn't be.

With a (probably too) quick view of the code, it seems to me that `chemmacros` should do `\bool_set_true:N \l__chemmacros_in_document_bool` in the definition of `\chemmacros_iupac:nn` so that all definitions are there when needed.

There are a few ways you can work around this, but the easiest one seems to swap the order that things get added to `\begin{document}`, so that the preamble "ends" before `\maketitle` (which is probably a good idea). To do that, just load `etoolbox` before `\documentclass{achemso}`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\title{Study of \iupac{1,2-di|methyl|benzene}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```